# How to display some text based on a condition inside a tabular environment?

Tags: macros, tables, conditionals, grouping

I defined a variable `\@afwezig` that holds people that were not present at a certain meeting.

```
\long\def\@afwezig{}
\def\afwezig#1{\def\@afwezig{#1}}
```

Now I want to make the header of the meeting report as follows :

```
\newcommand{\makeheader}{
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
  Aanwezig&: \@aanwezig \\
  Verontschuldigd&: \@verontschuldigd \\
 \ifx\@afwezig\@empty
  \relax
 \else
 Afwezig&: \@afwezig \\
 \fi %

\end{tabularx}

}
```

This is supposed to give a table with "Afwezig:" if I specify `\afwezig{somename}` in my document, but a table without the part "Afwezig:" if nothing is specified. Problem is, the part "Afwezig:" is displayed if I didn't specify '\afwezig', and I get tons of errors when I put `\afwezig{}` in my document file.

The first error:

> ! Incomplete \ifx; all text was
>   ignored after line 10.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS : could somebody create a label with condition or if-else or so? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should internally think about tabular cells as being local groups, so you can't open an `\ifx` in one cell and close it in another. To work around this problem, you need to use an expansion trick:

```
\ifx\@afwezig\@empty
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{}
{Afwezig&: \@afwezig \\}
```

In general, this is a much cleaner way to deal with TeX conditions.
Programming packages such as expl3 and etoolbox provide an easier way to write these constructs; e.g., in the former:

```
\tl_if_empty:NTF \@afwezig
  {}
  {Afwezig&: \@afwezig \\}
```

Comment: thx for the info. I figured out that if I delete the `\relax`, the code actually works as expected. I'll surely take a look at the packages you provided.

Comment: Even if it does in that case, be sure to be careful around conditionals and tabular material :-)

Comment: I realized. I took your advice and rewrote the part already. Thx again for the help.