# How can I single space long titles in my table of contents and list of figures/tables?

Tags: templates, line-spacing, thesis

I'm currently revising my university's thesis template, and I have almost everything fixed except for particular spacing issues. Our thesis manual states that long section titles must be single spaced, but even after enclosing the entire TOC in a singlespace environment, the long title still appears as double-spaced text. Using abbreviated titles are not allowed; titles must match in the table of contents and the body.

I've tried the fix outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49693/how-can-i-single-space-text-within-entries-of-my-table-of-contents) but it just double spaced the entire table of contents. I'm currently fiddling with the class file to see if there's anything in there I can do.

MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[SectionMethod, ListStyleI]{TAMUthesis2}

%\documentclass[ChapterMethod, ListStyleI]{TAMUthesis2}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

%FIX
\sloppy
\hfuzz=6pt
\vfuzz=6pt
\hbadness=2000
\vbadness=\maxdimen


%FIX
\graphicspath{{graphic/}}

\begin{document}


\include{data/cover}    %only store parameter
\maketitle


\frontmatter
\include{data/Abstract}
\include{data/Dedication}
\include{data/Acknowledgment}
\include{data/Contributors}
\include{data/Nomenclature}


\TAMUTableofContentsFormat  
%The line below add Word `F` on next page Table of Content (TOC). To add the third page word `Page`, Please apply the same command below at appropriate position.
\TAMUTocAddWordPage
\begin{singlespace}
    \tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}

\TAMUListOfFiguresFormat
\begin{singlespace}
    \listoffigures
\end{singlespace}


\TAMUListOfTablesFormat
%Uncomment the line below to add Word `Page' on next page of List of Figure
%\TAMULotAddWordPage    
\begin{singlespace}
    \listoftables
\end{singlespace}


\mainmatter
    \include{data/chapterI}
    \include{data/chapterII}
    \include{data/chapterIII}
    \include{data/chapterIV}
    %\include{data/AnotherChapter}


\TAMUReferenceFormat
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{myReference}


\appendix
\TAMUAppendixFormat     
%comment the line below if using ChapterMethod or there is no Appendix
\begin{appendices}

%keep this line always if you have appendix
    \include{data/Appendix}

%comment the line below if using ChapterMethod or no appendix
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Here is the class file `TAMUThesis2.cls` for which most was generated by the person that had this position last.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{TAMUthesis2}[2016/07/15 Texas A&M University Thesis Template Version 2.07.16 based on book.cls]

\newif\if@ChapterMethod\@ChapterMethodtrue
\DeclareOption{ChapterMethod}{\@ChapterMethodtrue}
\DeclareOption{SectionMethod}{\@ChapterMethodfalse}
%\ExecuteOptions{ChapterMethod} %default is ChapterMethod

\newif\if@ListStyle\@ListStyletrue
\DeclareOption{ListStyleI}{\@ListStyletrue}
\DeclareOption{ListStyleII}{\@ListStylefalse}


\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
%\ExecuteOptions{}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\showboxdepth=5
\showboxbreadth=5

\RequirePackage{{lscape}}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
%\RequirePackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing

\RequirePackage{adjustbox}


%\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
%  \begingroup
%  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
%  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
%  \endgroup
%}

%\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}

%\hfuzz=50pt

\LoadClass[12pt, letterpaper,oneside]{book}

\RequirePackage{textcomp}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{arydshln}
\RequirePackage{gensymb}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize}


\RequirePackage{rotating,booktabs} 



\RequirePackage[xetex,bookmarks, hidelinks]{hyperref}  % comment to disable hyper-link in table of contents

\RequirePackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\RequirePackage{color, graphicx} % Allows you to import images
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.4in, right=1.15in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{truncate}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Caption[2][130pt]{\captionof{figure}{\truncate{#1}{#2}}}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}

\RequirePackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{cont}{#1 continued #2#3\par}

\if@ChapterMethod

\else
    \RequirePackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\fi

\RequirePackage{setspace}
%\setstretch{1}
%\linespread{1.6}


%font type
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial}    %change font style to Arial
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\renewcommand*\large{\fontsize{14.05}{14.05}\selectfont}    %fine tunement to adjust \large to be 14pt exactly


%remove vertical space between itemize/enumerate/description
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%remove vertical space between items in itemize
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, nolistsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, nolistsep}
\setlist[description]{noitemsep, nolistsep}

%indent after chapter/sectioin, only affect the first one
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} %first indent


%Header/Footer Modification
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
%\lfoot{}
%\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\RequirePackage{titlesec}
%modify section title font size
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalfont\bfseries}


\if@ChapterMethod
    %chapter title format
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\large}
    %modify chapter title name
    \renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{CHAPTER}
\else
    %chapter title format
    \titleformat{\chapter}{\vspace{1ex}\large\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\large}
    %modify chapter title name
    %\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{CHAPTER}
\fi



\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX} % this command is overlapped by something else, I believe comment it won't cause any difference in APPENDIX title
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}


\RequirePackage{tocloft}
%enable that toc has no section number, no subsection number as well
\if@ChapterMethod
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}        %for section
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}                %for section
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}} %for subsection
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}             %for subsection
\fi



\addtocontents{toc}{\linespread{1.4}\selectfont}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0pt}
%\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip14pt}

\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{-7pt}
%\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}

\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsecskip{-7pt}
%\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}

%redefine section to have 14pt space in first appearance at toc
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus 0.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries%
  \ifnum\value{section}>1 \else \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{14pt}}\fi}}


%add vertical space in lof to have equal space for each figure item
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\noaddvspace}
\addtocontents{lof}{\linespread{2.1}\selectfont}
%add vertical space in lof to have equal space for each figure item
\addtocontents{lot}{\linespread{2.1}\selectfont}


\RequirePackage{afterpage}          %enable the "PAGE" or other information on the consequencing next page


\if@ListStyle
    %LIST STYLE I
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill {Page} \par}    %add "PAGE" to toc/lof/lot 
    %\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill \par}      %double space of toc word `'Page' and the chapter title.

    \addtocontents{lof}{{FIGURE}~\hfill {Page} \par}
    %\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill  \par}
    \addtocontents{lot}{{TABLE}~\hfill {Page} \par}
    %\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill \par}
\else
    %LIST STYLE II
    \addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill {Page} \par}
    \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill {Page} \par}
    %%list of figures with "FIGURE"
    \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure ~}
    \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table ~}
\fi



%modify the vertical space after title but before the content in toc/lof/lot
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{27pt}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{27pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{33pt}



%toc title
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}

\if@ChapterMethod
    \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }
    \renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
    %Chapter Roman Numbering
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\else
    %Chapter Arabic  Numbering
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\fi





%leader dots in TABLE OF CONTENTS
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters


\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
}

%modify toc/lof/lot font size and align horizontal middle
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centerline{LIST OF FIGURES}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centerline{LIST OF TABLES}}


%remove the vertical spacing before toc/lof/lot
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-6ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-5.5ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-2.4ex}


%modify the horizontal spacing  in lof/lot
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{4em}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}


%remove the vertical space above CHAPTER title in each chapter, not toc
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-5.5ex}{6ex}
%modify the vertical space above/below section/subsection title in the main content, not toc.
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}


%%change equation vertical space
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}% plus 1ex minus 1ex}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0ex  plus 1ex minus 1ex}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{4pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}%x plus 1ex minus 1ex}
}


%set figure/table display method to be Arabic.arabic instead of following chapter Roman Number.
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}



%new environment definition
\newenvironment{Contfigure}{%
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure} Continued.}%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure} Continued.}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\begin{figure}}{%
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure} }
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure} }
\end{figure}}



%new environment definition
\newenvironment{Conttable}{%
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{table} Continued.}%
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table} Continued.}%
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\begin{table}}{%
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{table} }
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\end{table}}
%command must be used when applying Contfigure and Conttable %\captionsetup{list=no} %disable figures/table to appear in lof/lot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%hook definition

\AtBeginDocument{
    \pagestyle{empty} 
    \pagenumbering{roman} 
}
\renewcommand\frontmatter{
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{2} %abstract page number starts from 2.
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \linespread{2}\selectfont
}


\newcommand{\TAMUTableofContentsFormat}{
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill \par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together with package{afterpage}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
}


\newcommand{\TAMUTocAddWordPage}{
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip\vspace{1ex}}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc,

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill \par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together
%this is a manual way to do so, pleaer refer to http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=252
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}

\newcommand{\TAMUListOfFiguresFormat}{
    \newpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}

    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill \par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together with package{afterpage}
}

\newcommand{\TAMULofAddWordPage}{
\if@ListStyle
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{\noindent{FIGURE}~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip\vspace{-1ex}}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc,
\else
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip\vspace{-1ex}}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc,
\fi
}

\newcommand{\TAMULotAddWordPage}{
\if@ListStyle
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\afterpage{\noindent{TABLE}~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip\vspace{-1ex}}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc,
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill \par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together
%this is a manul way to do so, pleaer refer to http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=252
\else
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip\vspace{-1ex}}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc,
\fi
}

\newcommand{\TAMUListOfTablesFormat}{
    \linespread{1}\selectfont
    \newpage
    \phantomsection %optional for hyper-ref:
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}

     %
%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\afterpage{{TABLE}~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together with package{afterpage}
%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill{Page}\par\medskip}} %command to enable second page "PAGE" in toc, together with package{afterpage}
}


\newcommand{\TAMUAbstractFormat}{
    %\cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection %optional for hyperref
    %\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
%   \begin{spacing}{2}
    \begin{center}
    \MakeUppercase{\textbf{\large Abstract}}
    %       \MakeUppercase
    \end{center}
    \vspace{14pt}
}

\newcommand{\TAMUContributorFormat}{
    %\cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection %optional for hyperref
    %\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Contributors and Funding Sources}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTRIBUTORS AND FUNDING SOURCES}
%   \begin{spacing}{2}
    \begin{center}
    \MakeUppercase{\textbf{\large Contributors and Funding Sources}}
    %       \MakeUppercase
    \end{center}
    \vspace{14pt}
}

\newcommand{\TAMUNomenclatureFormat}{
    %\cleardoublepage
    %\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract
    \phantomsection %optional for hyperref
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{NOMENCLATURE}

    \begin{center}
    \MakeUppercase{\textbf{\large Nomenclature}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{14pt}
}

\newcommand{\TAMUDedicationFormat}{
%\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
%\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEDICATION}

}

\newcommand{\TAMUAcknowledgmentFormat}{
    \phantomsection %optional for hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\begin{center}
\MakeUppercase{\textbf{\large Acknowledgments}}
\end{center}
\vspace{14pt} 
}

\newcommand{\TAMUReferenceFormat}{
    \newpage
    \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
}

\newcommand{\TAMUAppendixFormat}{
    \captionsetup{list=no} %disable figures/table to appear in lof/lot
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}   %fixed the bug caused by Figure/Table Continued, all appendix figure/table in appendix will be labeled as A.1, A.2, A.3...
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}} %fixed the bug caused by Figure/Table Continued, all appendix figure/table in appendix labeled as A.1, A.2
\if@ChapterMethod
    \renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{APPENDIX}  % some unknown bugs, comment this line will cause the Appendix title in main content becomes CHAPTER A instead of APPENDIX A
    \updatechaptername  %this cmd is needed for chatper method to update toc title for appendix
\fi
}


\renewcommand\mainmatter{
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \linespread{2}\selectfont
}

%end of hook definition

\let\@documentname\@empty
\let\@degreename\@empty
\let\@majorname\@empty

\let\@ChairOfCommittee\@empty
\let\@CoChairOfCommittee\@empty
\let\@CommitteeMemberOne\@empty
\let\@CommitteeMemberTwo\@empty
\let\@CommitteeMemberThree\@empty
\let\@CommitteeMemberFour\@empty
\let\@HeadOfDepartment\@empty

\let\@GraduateMonth\@empty
\let\@GraduateYear\@empty

\let\@GradMajor\@empty


\newcommand{\TAMUdocument}[1]{\def\@documentname{#1}}\TAMUdocument{Thesis/Dissertation/Record of Study}
\def\@TAMUdocument{\@documentname}
\newcommand{\TAMUdegree}[1]{\def\@degreename{#1}}\TAMUdegree{Master of Science}
\def\@TAMUdegree{\@degreename}


\newcommand{\ChairOfCommitteeName}[1]{\def\@ChairOfCommittee{#1}}\ChairOfCommitteeName{Chair's Name}
\def\@ChairOfCommitteeName{\@ChairOfCommittee}
\newcommand{\CommitteeMemberOneName}[1]{\def\@CommitteeMemberOne{#1}}\CommitteeMemberOneName{Committee Member One's Name}
\def\@CommitteeMemberOneName{\@CommitteeMemberOne}
\newcommand{\CommitteeMemberTwoName}[1]{\def\@CommitteeMemberTwo{#1}}\CommitteeMemberTwoName{Committee Member Two's Name}
\def\@CommitteeMemberTwoName{\@CommitteeMemberTwo}

\newcommand{\HeadOfDepartmentName}[1]{\def\@HeadOfDepartment{#1}}\HeadOfDepartmentName{Head Of Department's Name}
\def\@HeadOfDepartmentName{\@HeadOfDepartment}

\newcommand{\CoChairOfCommitteeName}[1]{\def\@CoChairOfCommittee{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommitteeMemberThreeName}[1]{\def\@CommitteeMemberThree{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommitteeMemberFourName}[1]{\def\@CommitteeMemberFour{#1}}

\newcommand{\TAMUgradMonth}[1]{\def\@GraduateMonth{#1}}\TAMUgradMonth{May/August/December}
\def\@TAMUgradMonth{\@GraduateMonth}
\newcommand{\TAMUgradYear}[1]{\def\@GraduateYear{#1}}\TAMUgradYear{20XX}
\def\@TAMUgradYear{\@GraduateYear}

\newcommand{\TAMUmajor}[1]{\def\@GradMajor{#1}}\TAMUmajor{Your Major}
\def\@TAMUmajor{\@GradMajor}


\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{spacing}{2.1}
        {\large\bfseries\@title\par}
        \vspace{17mm} \par
        A \@documentname \par
        by \par
        \MakeUppercase{\@author} \\     
    \end{spacing}
    \vspace{8mm}\par
    {Submitted to the Office of Graduate and Professional Studies of  \par
        Texas A\&M University \par
    in partial fulfillment of the requirement for the degree of \par
%           \vspace{9mm}    
            \vspace{14pt}   
        \MakeUppercase{\@degreename}
    }
    \end{center}
%   \vspace{6mm}
    \vspace{24pt}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        Chair of Committee,     &   \@ChairOfCommittee  \\ 
        %
        \ifx\@CoChairOfCommittee\@empty %
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else %
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi %
        {}          %
        {Co-Chair of Committee,& \@CoChairOfCommittee  \\ }%

        Committee Members,  &   \@CommitteeMemberOne        \\
                        &    \@CommitteeMemberTwo       \\  %
        \ifx\@CommitteeMemberThree\@empty %
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else %
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo %
        \fi     %
        {}  %
        { & \@CommitteeMemberThree  \\} %
        \ifx\@CommitteeMemberFour\@empty %
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else %
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo %
        \fi %
        {}%
        { & \@CommitteeMemberFour   \\} %
        %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4072/how-to-display-some-text-based-on-a-condition-inside-a-tabular-environment
        Head of Department,     &   \@HeadOfDepartment  \\  
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{31pt} \par
        \@GraduateMonth         %August%December %
        ~   %
        \@GraduateYear              % 20XX
        %university requires that graduating data must be
        \par
        \vspace{40pt}
        Major Subject:  \@GradMajor
        \par
        \vspace{42pt}
        Copyright  \@GraduateYear %
        ~\@author
    \end{center}
}

\endinput
```

[image: Partial Output showing long title]

I apologize for the length of code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where can `TAMUthesis2.cls` be found?

Comment: This page, http://howdy.me/template-download/, V1.7, makes particular reference to fixing TOC spacing in the  TAMU thesis template (though I cannot find reference to `TAMUthesis2.cls`, only `TAMUthesis.cls` at http://ogaps.tamu.edu/New-Current-Students/Thesis-and-Dissertation-Services/Document-Template#0-BasicTemplate)

Comment: That was for an older template version; I also apologize for the lack of TAMUthesis2.cls. I will include it as soon as I can.